# Get the text of a RichEdit50W window using TWAPI

Tags: winapi, tcl

I would like to retrieve the text of a specific window. Using

```
twapi::get_window_text $handle
```

I get the caption of the window. But how can I get the actual content ? In C++ I was using

```
EM_GETLINE
```

How can I use these raw Windows API functions from TCL? For EM_GETLINE for example I have to define the numbers of lines to be fetched and the buffer where they shall be stored.

Could someone show me how to use raw Windows API functions from TCL or point me to a site where I can find examples? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send messages with Twapi's raw-API. I'm not fammilar with the the exact details how this message works, but you know that probably better than me:

```
package require twapi
proc get_richedit_text {hwnd line} {
    set MAX_LEN 0x0100
    # You have to lookup this value in the header.
    set EM_GETLINE 0x00C4
    set bufsize [expr {2 * ($MAX_LEN + 1)}]
    # yes, twapi has malloc.
    set szbuf [twapi::malloc $bufsize]
    # catch everything, so we can free the buffer.
    catch {
        # set the first word to the size. Whatever a word is.
        # I assume it is an int (type 1), but if it is a int64, use type 5, wchar is 3.
        # arguments to Twapi_WriteMemory: type pointer(void*) offset bufferlen value 
        twapi::Twapi_WriteMemory 1 $szbuf 0 $bufsize $MAX_LEN
        # send the message. You don't have SendMessage, only SendMessageTimeout
        set ressize [twapi::SendMessageTimeout $hwnd $EM_GETLINE $line [twapi::pointer_to_address $szbuf] 0x0008 1000]
        return [twapi::Twapi_ReadMemory 3 $szbuf 0 [expr {$ressize * 2}]]
    } res opt
    # free the buffer.
    twapi::free $szbuf
    return -options $opt $res
}
```

I used some internal/undocumented twapi API, the only documentation is twapi's source code.

Comment: If you want to get the number of lines in the richedit, use `::twapi::SendMessageTimeout $hwnd 0x00BA 0 0 0x0008 1000`. (EM_GETLINECOUNT)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. Unfortunately I get  "invalid command name "twapi::Twapi_WriteMemory" "  when trying to use the proc. I use TWAPI 3.1.17. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: In the TWAPI source I (and the TCL) can't find "::twapi::pointer_to_address" either. Which version did you use?

Comment: I use 4.0b22. This is a beta version. I found the commands `::twapi::Twapi_WriteMemoryInt`, `::twapi::Twapi_PtrToAddress` and `::twapi::Twapi_ReadMemoryUnicode`. That is the downside of an internal API.

Comment: @Lumpi Note that I found this commands with 3.1.17. They should work, although I did not test it. An other way is to write your own Tcl extension. (The handles that twapi returns are just a list. 1st element is the address, 2nd is the type, e.g. `12345 HWND`)